# Combining 2 queries into 1 query

Tags: sql

How would I combine the results of the first query with the second query where the `EMPLID` column for both the `Z_EMP_YAN` table and the `Z_OPRDEFN` table match up?

```
select b.OPRID
from Z_EMP_BENFT a, PSOPRDEFN b
WHERE a.EMPLID = b.EMPLID
AND A.Z_PEND_COVER = 'Y'
AND OPRID LIKE 'ZZ%'

select EMPLID from z_emp_yan where z_yan_action_id = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT b.oprid 
FROM   ps_z_emp_benft a, 
       psoprdefn b, 
       ps_z_emp_yan c 
WHERE  a.emplid = b.emplid 
       AND a.emplid = c.emplid 
       AND A.z_pend_cover = 'Y' 
       AND oprid LIKE 'ZZ%' 
       AND c.z_yan_action_id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing really wrong with the previous post, I just prefer using `Joins`:

```
select b.oprid 
from ps_z_emp_benft a
    join psoprdefn b on a.emplid = b.emplid 
    join ps_z_emp_yan c on a.emplid = c.emplid 
where A.z_pend_cover = 'Y' 
    and oprid LIKE 'ZZ%' 
    and c.z_yan_action_id = 1
```